# Prove that, in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, if $(\overline{a})^2 = (\overline{b})^2$ then $\overline{a}=\overline{b}\lor\overline{a}=\overline{-b}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $p$ be a positive prime number. Prove that, in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, if $(\overline{a})^2 = (\overline{b})^2$ then $\overline{a}=\overline{b}\lor\overline{a}=\overline{-b}$. Then prove that, if $p$ is odd, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ has exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ squares different from zero.

I managed to do the first part. Here's what I've done:

In $\mathbb{Z}_p$, every non zero element is invertible. Then $\exists \overline{s} \in\mathbb{Z}_p$ s.t. $\overline{sa}=\overline{1}$. From that follows that $(\overline{as})^2=\overline{1}$. However, from that we have $(\overline{bs})^2=\overline{1}$. But from that it follows that $(\overline{a})^2=(\overline{b})^2$, so we must have $\overline{a}=\overline{b}\lor\overline{a}=-\overline{b}$.

Now, as for the second part, I'm not sure how to tackle the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nonzero squares are $1^2=(-1)^2$, $2^2=(-2)^2$, ..., $(\frac{p-1}{2})^2=(-\frac{p-1}{2})^2$. Note that we've covered all $a^2$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}/(p)$, and none of them is repeated beacuse of what you just proved.